# Why is $\sum_{k = n}^{\infty} (\log k)^2/k^2 = O \left((\log n)^2/n \right)$?

Tags: asymptotics

The question comes from a statement in Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik on page 465.

$$\sum_{k \geq n} \frac{(\log k)^2}{k^2} = O \left(\frac{(\log n)^2}{n} \right).$$

How is this calculated?

Comment: I removed the $O(...)$ from the left side, I think this is the right notation.

Comment: A standard thing to try here is summation by parts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: You can guess the result replacing the sum by an integral, integrating by parts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a pretty straightforward solution. The idea is to split the sum up into a main part and an error term, and generalizes to many sums where the integral test won't work because the corresponding integral is difficult.

First recall that we have $\sum_{k \ge n} \frac{1}{k^s} = O \left( \frac{1}{n^{s-1}} \right)$ (for example by the integral test, although for integer $s$ there is a more elementary way to see this). Split the sum as

$$\sum_{k=n}^{n^2} \frac{(\log k)^2}{k^2} + \sum_{k \ge n^2+1} \frac{(\log k)^2}{k^2}.$$

Since $(\log k)^2$ is eventually bounded by $k^{\epsilon}$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, the second term is $O \left( \frac{1}{n^{4-2\epsilon}} \right)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. On the other hand, the first term is at most

$$\sum_{k=n}^{n^2} \frac{(\log n^2)^2}{k^2} \le 4 (\log n)^2 \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = O \left( \frac{(\log n)^2}{n} \right).$$

(Note that unlike the argument using the integral test, this argument doesn't optimize the constant as it stands. But one can actually replace $n^2$ with $n^{1+\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and the argument carries through, and taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ gives the correct constant.)

---

For a fun exercise in splitting sums, try getting an optimal bound for the sum described in [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/optimizing-parameters/).

Comment: +1, I don't fully understand why this is the least voted answer.  The other solutions are ad hoc, and only work in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that problem, Qiaochu.  I was able to show that the bound is $O(1/\sqrt{n})$.  [Here's my write-up](http://mathstat.dal.ca/~antoniov/asympsum.html).

Comment: @Antonio: very nice!

Answer (score 10):

I think the easiest way here is to simply find $\displaystyle \int_k ^{\infty} \frac {(\log x)^2}{x^2}dx$. After some work, it turns out to be $\dfrac{\log k(\log k + 2) + 2}{k}$. Oh - but I'm also somewhat confident that Qiaochu's suggestion to Sum by Parts would work as well (and give almost the same answer).

Comment: Will a sum always have the asymptotic properties of its integral?

Comment: @acetv: for non-negative monotonically decreasing functions, yes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence .

Answer (score 5):

Note that the function $f$ defined by 
$$
f(x) = \frac{{(\log x)^2 }}{{x^2 }}
$$
is decreasing for $x > x_0$ (for some $x_0 > 0$), and that
$$
\frac{{\frac{d}{{dx}}\int_x^\infty  {\frac{{(\log t)^2 }}{{t^2 }}dt} }}{{\frac{d}{{dx}}\frac{{(\log x)^2 }}{x}}} = \frac{{ - \frac{{(\log x)^2 }}{{x^2 }}}}{{\frac{{2\log x - (\log x)^2 }}{{x^2 }}}} = \frac{{ - \log x}}{{2 - \log x}} \to 1 \;\; {\rm as} \;\; x \to \infty ,
$$
hence also
$$
\frac{{\int_x^\infty  {\frac{{(\log t)^2 }}{{t^2 }}dt} }}{{\frac{{(\log x)^2 }}{x}}} \to 1 \;\; {\rm as} \;\; x \to \infty.
$$

EDIT (elaborating; what follows also completes mixedmath's answer):

With $f$ as above,
$$
f'(x) = \frac{{2\log x(1 - \log x)}}{{x^3 }},
$$
implying that $f$ is decreasing on $[e,\infty)$. It follows that for any $n \geq 3$,
$$
\int_n^\infty  {f(x)\,dx} \leq \sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {f(k)}  \leq f(n) + \int_n^\infty  {f(x)\,dx} .
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{{\int_n^\infty  {f(x)\,dx} }}{{\frac{{(\log n)^2 }}{n}}} \le \frac{{\sum\nolimits_{k = n}^\infty  {f(k)} }}{{\frac{{(\log n)^2 }}{n}}} \le \frac{{f(n)}}{{\frac{{(\log n)^2 }}{n}}} + \frac{{\int_n^\infty  {f(x)\,dx} }}{{\frac{{(\log n)^2 }}{n}}}.
$$
So from
$$
\frac{{f(n)}}{{\frac{{(\log n)^2 }}{n}}} = \frac{1}{n} \to 0
$$
and
$$
\frac{{\int_n^\infty  {\frac{{(\log x)^2 }}{{x^2 }}\,dx} }}{{\frac{{(\log n)^2 }}{n}}} \to 1 
$$ 
as $n \to \infty$, it follows that
$$
\frac{{\sum\nolimits_{k = n}^\infty  {f(k)} }}{{\frac{{(\log n)^2 }}{n}}} \to 1.
$$

Comment: That's pretty cool. I like that.